# How to make client wait for server response after client sends information

Tags: javascript

```
//Server side code

app.post("/handle-coordinates", async function (req, res) {
    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=${req.body.coordinates.lat}, ${req.body.coordinates.long}&destinations=${req.body.coordinates.lat2},${req.body.coordinates.long2}&units=imperial&key=KEY`,
      headers: {}
    };

    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text));
        res.send(response.data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

  })


app.listen(4242, () => console.log(`Node server listening on port ${4242}!`));
```

```
//Client side code
var form = document.getElementById("form")
var origin = document.getElementById("origin")
var destination = document.getElementById("destination")



form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    var formSubmitted = true
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitted");
    var formData = {
        lat: document.getElementById("lat").value,
        long: document.getElementById("long").value,
        lat2: document.getElementById("lat2").value,
        long2: document.getElementById("long2").value,
    };
    console.log(formData);
    fetch('/handle-coordinates', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ coordinates: formData })
    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result)
      })
    origin.value = ""
    destination.value = ""
});
```

In this code, my client is sending 2 pairs of latitude and longitude coordinates to my server on the /handle-coordinates endpoint. My server successfully sends a request to google maps api and then retrieves the distance from the Google Maps api response. It then sends this back on the /handle-coordinates endpoint. Using inspect, I can successfully see that the /handle-coordinates endpoint has the number of miles on its page. My goal is to log the number of miles to the console.

I tried using

```
.then(function(result) {
        console.log(result)
      })
```

but it just resulted in :Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:4242/handle-coordinates', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body
:
(...)
bodyUsed
:
false
headers
:
Headers {}
ok
:
true
redirected
:
false
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
type
:
"basic"
url
:
"http://localhost:4242/handle-coordinates"

[Image of result after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6NWj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec for the fetch API requires the promise resolution to contain a [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response). According to the MDN documentation there are a few different instance methods that can be used to extract the body:

> `Response.formData()`
>
> Returns a promise that resolves with a FormData representation of the response body.
>
> `Response.json()`
>
> Returns a promise that resolves with the result of parsing the response body text as JSON.
>
> `Response.text()`
>
> Returns a promise that resolves with a text representation of the response body.

I suspect you're looking for `Response.json()`.

I would also refactor your implementation to use `async/await` syntax:

client-side:

```
const origin = document.getElementById("origin");
const destination = document.getElementById("destination");
let formSubmitted = false;

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  formSubmitted = true;
  event.preventDefault();

  const formPayload = {
    lat: document.getElementById("lat").value,
    long: document.getElementById("long").value,
    lat2: document.getElementById("lat2").value,
    long2: document.getElementById("long2").value,
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch('/handle-coordinates', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ coordinates: formData })
    });

    const responseJson = await response.json()
    console.log(responseJson);
    origin.value = ""
    destination.value = ""
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error submitting form: ', error);
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => handleSubmit(event));
```

server-side:

```
try {
 const { data } = await axios(config);
 res.json({ distance: data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text });
} catch (error) {
 console.log(error);
 res.status(500).end();
}
```

Comment: I now get Promise {<pending>}  and when I expand it I see the distance in the PromiseResult section in the console, how would I refer to that specific PromiseResult so I can display it to my html page.

Comment: @KaviGupta where are you getting `Promise { <pending> }`?

Comment: I am getting it in the console I have added link to image https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6NWj.png

Comment: @KaviGupta Where in the code is that being logged?

Comment: the line console.log(response.json()); in client.js is logging it in the console of the localhost page

Comment: @KaviGupta Ah, apologies, response.json() is an async method, you can change it to:

```
const responseJson = await response.json()
console.log(responseJson);
```

I've editited my answer